# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE_URL'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve the placeholder 'BASE_URL'` even though I have the properties added to my `application.properties` file. Honestly, my feignClient where this value is to be used picks it up from `application.proprties` which further resolves the value from local.env file. I also noticed that some of my properties are shown to be unused by IntelliJ even though I have used them. Attaching my code usage, `application.properties` and local.env for better understanding below

Feign Client:

```
@FeignClient(value = "${service.name}", url = "${base.url}")
public interface BuddyClient {

    @PostMapping(
            value = "${primary.user.url}",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    ResponseEntity<PrimaryUserCreationResponse> createAccount(
            @RequestHeader("Content-Type") String contentType,
            @RequestHeader("PartnerName") String partnerName,
            @RequestHeader("PartnerKey") String partnerKey,
            @Payload PrimayUserCreationRequest request
    ) throws TimeoutException;
}
```

application.properties

```
service.name=buddy //IntelliJ shows unused
base.url=${BASE_URL} //IntelliJ shows unused
primary.user.url=${PRIMARY_USER_URL} //IntelliJ shows used
```

local.env

```
BASE_URL=https://externalapi.in
PRIMARY_USER_URL=/api/User
```

Complete error

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2021-11-04T01:54:15.351Z",
  "log.level": "ERROR",
  "message": "Application run failed",
  "service.name": "-integrations-service",
  "process.thread.name": "main",
  "log.logger": "org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication",
  "error.type": "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException",
  "error.message": "Invalid bean definition with name 'comintegrations.core.external.client.Client' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'base_url' in value \"http://${base_url}\"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'base_url' in value \"http://${base_url}\"",
  "error.stack_trace": "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'comintegrations.core.external.client.Client' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'base_url' in value \"http://${base_url}\"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'base_url' in value \"http://${base_url}\"\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:228)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:182)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:157)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:125)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:342)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)\n\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:336)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:252)\n\tat java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:251)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)\n\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)\n\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)\n\tat org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)\n\tat org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)\n\tat org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)\n\tat org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)\n\tat org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)\n\tat com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)\n\tat com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)\n\tat com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)\n\tat com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'base_url' in value \"http://${base_url}\"\n\tat org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178)\n\tat org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)\n\tat org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236)\n\tat org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:296)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:222)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:147)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:85)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:225)\n\t. 75 more\n"
}
```

Comment: `BUDDY_BASE_URL` doesn't appear in your "Complete error"

Comment: @tgdavies I actually removed the Buddy while writing the code here since it's an organisation code. Apologies for the inconsistencies. I have edited the question now

Answer (score 0):

I guess for local.env
BASE_URL belongs to internal scripts
and BUDDY_BASE_URL should be in local.env
and/or perhaps the "http://" protocol prefix should not be on the url value.